# Traffic inspection with Fiddler on a device with no proxy option

Tags: networking, proxy, fiddler

I have an embedded device that has no official firmware available for download. However it has a built-in function to check for updates.

It can connect to WiFi (and WiFi only!), but has no proxy options at all. So I can't set up Fiddler.

My router does not support setting a local proxy, so I'm trying to use Connectify - but it does not support setting a proxy on that connection either.

What are my options in capturing the update request to obtain a stock firmware?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a sniffer like Wireshark or Ethereal to monitor the TCP/IP traffic.